# How to make a client mail in ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, mailer

I need to make a mailer client in Ruby on Rails App. I need to send mails FROM multiple address, can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `from` param of the `mail` method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail in ActionMailer.